# SQL Server : scheduled notification

Tags: sql-server

I am working on a database that have scheduled medical vacinese. I am wondering what is best approach to notify clients on the schedules before 2 days without running a third party software that keep checking the schedules. I need a guide to the best approach to do it by notification if possible or any other easy approach that have less cost and best performance.

Comment: This question is very broad and doesn't even nail down the notification delivery method.

Comment: ok so what is your advice in such case if we will not use sql notifcation

Comment: A list of things that are a *Notification*: Push Notification to Mobile, Message Sent to a Facebook account, An email, Phone Call, Text Message, Raven with a note attached to its foot. You are not telling the community enough information to make the best advice possible, and are not narrowing down our options for scope of advice. You could write a SQL job to execute every morning and send a email, or you could develop an in-house notification system with SIP phone calls. Or you could train ravens to carry notes...

Comment: ya thats is what i am talking about. the problem not the notification it self. the problem is querying and runing the job

Comment: If you are using email, you can use the built in SQL Agent to run jobs on a regular  schedule that send out emails.

Comment: that answers my question. thank you

Comment: Are you asking about pool vs push?

Comment: @Horaciux no the pool was the issue and sql agent job is the solution. thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to look at a feature called SQL Server Agent, which allows you to schedule jobs to run on your SQL Server - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189237.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396